# JAXB class eclipse wizard didn't generate enums

Tags: eclipse, enums, xsd, jaxb

I am new to schema and JAXB APIs. So I tried to learn by trying out some examples.
I tried to generate JAXB classes using eclipse wizard, but startngely it didn't genearte any enums.

part of XSD is as follows which used to genearate classes,

```
<complexType name="ShipOrderType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="orderperson" type="string"></element>
        <element name="shipto" type="tns:shiptoType"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="orderid" type="int" use="required"></attribute>
</complexType>

<complexType name="shiptoType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string">
        </element>
        <element name="city">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="string">
                    <enumeration value="Bangalore"></enumeration>
                    <enumeration value="Mysore"></enumeration>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="orderid" type="string"></attribute>
</complexType>
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug in eclipse?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I may have not the best solution but it should work:
Extract the simpleType from the complexType and give it a name.

```
<complexType name="ShipOrderType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="orderperson" type="string"></element>
        <element name="shipto" type="tns:shiptoType"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="orderid" type="int" use="required"></attribute>
</complexType>

<complexType name="shiptoType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string">
        </element>
        <element name="city" type="City">
        </element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="orderid" type="string"></attribute>
</complexType>

<simpleType name="City">
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="Bangalore"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="Mysore"></enumeration>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Perhaps, if you don't extract the simple type but only name it will also work.